# How to open multiple modals on one page with data from an API

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, modal-dialog, github-api

I currently have a web page that is grabbing the public events data from the Github API. For each of the data, I have it where it will generate a button to display the info on to the page and a div to display some more info as a modal. I have the modal hidden by default. I am trying to get it to where each time I press the button, the respective modal will appear. I have tried researching this and the methods I found just doesn't work with my code and I can't figure out why. I guess it's because my elements are generated instead of hard-coding it in the HTML file? I am still new to JavaScript so I really want to stick to the basic first, and have this done with vanillaJS if possible.

My code:

```js
function loadEvents()
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/events', true);
  xhr.onload = function()
  {
    if(this.status == 200)
    {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      var output = '';
      var modalResult = '';
      for(var i in response)
      {
        output +=
        //I'm using the id of the events to add on to the name of data-modal as a way of matching it up to the id of the modal later
        '<button class="pubEvents" data-modal="modal'+response[i].id+'">' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li><b>Username:</b> '+response[i].actor.login+'</li>' +
        '<li><b>Event Type:</b> '+response[i].type+'</li>' +
        '<li><b>Repo:</b> '+response[i].repo.name+'</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</button>' +
        '<div id="modal'+response[i].id+'" class="bgModal">' + //The id of the modal should match with the button attribute data-modal
        '<div class="modalContent">' +
        '<div class="modalHeader">' +
        '<span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>' +
        '<img src="'+response[i].actor.avatar_url+'"class="avatar" width="100px" height="100px">' +
        '<h2><b>'+response[i].actor.login+'</b></h2>' +
        '</div>' + //modalHeader
        '<div class="modalBody">' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li><b>Event Type:</b> '+response[i].type+'</li>' +
        '<li><b>Repo:</b> '+response[i].repo.name+'</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>' + //modalBody
        '<div class="modalFooter">' +
        '<h2><a href="https://github.com/'+response[i].repo.name+'" target="_blank">Check out this repository here!</a></h2>' +
        '</div>' + //modalFooter
        '</div>' + //modalContent
        '</div>' //modalBox
        ;
      }
      document.getElementById('bodyContainer').innerHTML = output;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function refresh()
{
  location.reload(true);
}

//Here is my code where I try to "connect" the modal to its respective button
//Select all the button of events
var modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.pubEvents');
if(modalBtn) //If modalBtn exists
{
  //For each button, create an 'onclick' event
  modalBtn.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.onclick = function()
    {
      //Get the data-modal attribute of the button to "compare/match" to the id element of the modal
      var modalID = btn.getAttribute('data-modal');
      document.getElementById(modalID).style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body
{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navbar
{
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: #4AAAA5;
  color: #35404F;
}
#navbar ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#navbar ul li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover
{
  color: #A3D39C;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected
{
  border: 2px solid #A3D39C;
}
.pubEvents
{
  background-color: # #F0F0F0;
  border: 2px solid #4AAAA5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #35404F;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
.pubEvents ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
#bodyContainer
{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.pubEvents:hover
{
  background-color: #A3D39C;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bgModal
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  cursor: default;
}
.modalContent
{
  background-color:#F4F4F4;
  color: #35404F;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width:50%;
//height: 25%;
}
#modalContent ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.modalHeader h2
{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.modalHeader
{
  background: #4AAAA5;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #35404F;
}
.modalBody
{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.modalFooter
{
  background: #4AAAA5;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.modalFooter h2
{
  font-size: 25px;
}
.modalFooter a
{
  color: #35404F;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.modalFooter a:hover
{
  color: #7CCCC5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.avatar
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.closeBtn
{
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.closeBtn:hover
{
  color: #7CCCC5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#refreshBtn
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #7CCCC5;
  border: 2px solid #35404F;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #35404F;
}
#refreshBtn:hover
{
  background-color: #A3D39C;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link href="ghDashboardCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Github Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body onload="loadEvents()">
  <div id="navbar">
    <h1>Github Dashboard</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="selected">PUBLIC EVENTS</a></li>
      <li><a>PERSONAL EVENTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="bodyContainer">

  </div>
  <button id="refreshBtn" onclick="refresh()">&#8635;<br>Refresh</button>

  <script src="publicScript.js"></script>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML. You might want to fix that.

Comment: Where do you mean specifically? Because if you're talking about this line:

Comment: `<div id="modalContent">`

Comment: '<div id="modal'+response[i].id+'" class="bgModal">' then the id is actually unique. I have used the public events id to attach to the end of the modal. So the id for each modal is: modal# (# is whatever number the public events id is)

Comment: Ah ok. Let me try that.

Comment: instead of creating a new modal for every entry just save the entry in an `object array` with key and value and pass that key to a function on button click then display the modal with the values in it.